# functions in .Rprofile are not found with are in .env

Tags: r, rprofile

I have a .Rprofile I have copied from https://www.r-bloggers.com/fun-with-rprofile-and-customizing-r-startup/ However, when I load my R session the functions that are in `env$` they don't work and the functions not in `env` works perfectly, here is an example:

```
sshhh <- function(a.package){
   suppressWarnings(suppressPackageStartupMessages(
   library(a.package, character.only=TRUE)))
}

 auto.loads <-c("dplyr", "ggplot2")

if(interactive()){
  invisible(sapply(auto.loads, sshhh))
 }

.env <- new.env()
attach(.env)

.env$unrowname <- function(x) {
 rownames(x) <- NULL
x 
}

.env$unfactor <- function(df){
 id <- sapply(df, is.factor)
 df[id] <- lapply(df[id], as.character)
 df
 }

message("n*** Successfully loaded .Rprofile ***n")
```

Once R is loaded I can type `sshhh` and it shows the function, but if I type `unfactor` it shows `object not found`

Any help? Should I put all the functions on my workspace???

Comment: perhaps you should `attach(.env)` after all your functions are defined not midway through

Comment: I will `attach(.env)` and see if it works, although I have it added

Comment: you would need to attach after you add the function to .env.

Comment: ps given that creating packages is now almost effortless it may be worth creating one and adding your functions to it, to save messing about with attaching environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They functions created in a separate environment are intentionally hidden. This is to protect them from calls to `rm(list=ls())`.

From the original article:

> [Lines 58-59]: This creates a new hidden namespace that we can store
>   some functions in. We need to do this in order for these functions to
>   survive a call to “rm(list=ls())” which will remove everything in the
>   current namespace. This is described wonderfully in this blog post [1].

To use the unfactor function, you would call `.env$unfactor()`.

If you want to make those function available in the global namespace without having to refer to `.env`, you can simply leave out the whole `.env` part and just add the function the same way you did for the `sshhh` function.

[1] http://gettinggeneticsdone.blogspot.com.es/2013/07/customize-rprofile.html

Comment: Thanks @KeithHughitt but how can I make this functions available, when I start the R session? should I load the environment?

Comment: Just drop the `.env$` part when you define the functions and assign them the same way you did for `sshhh()` function.

Comment: @KeithHughittl; if `attach(.env)` is added to the .Rprofile script after the `.env$unfactor` function is defined, you can then access the function via `unfactor`